# React native hermes sampling crashes the app

Tags: react-native, react-native-hermes

I'm trying to do some sampling on our react native application, I enable sampling, but as soon as I disable it instead of showing a toast for the location of the file, the app immediately crashes and I get the below log from logcat:

```
03-30 17:24:18.753  2131  8334 W LocationOracle: No location history returned by ContextManager
03-30 17:24:18.753  2131  7501 W ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
03-30 17:24:18.753  2131  7501 W ErrorProcessor: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.b.g: Error reading from input stream
03-30 17:24:18.753  2131  7501 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.j.a.a(SourceFile:28)
03-30 17:24:18.753  2131  7501 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.j.b.run(SourceFile:15)
03-30 17:24:18.753  2131  7501 W ErrorProcessor:    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
03-30 17:24:18.753  2131  7501 W ErrorProcessor:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
03-30 17:24:18.753  2131  7501 W ErrorProcessor:    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
03-30 17:24:18.753  2131  7501 W ErrorProcessor:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
03-30 17:24:18.753  2131  7501 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ag.run(Unknown Source:4)
03-30 17:24:18.753  2131  7501 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bo.run(SourceFile:4)
03-30 17:24:18.753  2131  7501 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bo.run(SourceFile:4)
03-30 17:24:18.753  2131  7501 W ErrorProcessor:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
03-30 17:24:18.753  2131  7501 W ErrorProcessor:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
03-30 17:24:18.753  2131  7501 W ErrorProcessor:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
03-30 17:24:18.753  2131  7501 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:6)
03-30 17:24:18.753  2131  7501 W ErrorProcessor: Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
03-30 17:24:18.753  2131  7501 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.f(SourceFile:103)
03-30 17:24:18.753  2131  7501 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.au.read(SourceFile:2)
03-30 17:24:18.753  2131  7501 W ErrorProcessor:    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
03-30 17:24:18.753  2131  7501 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ao.run(SourceFile:18)
03-30 17:24:18.753  2131  7501 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.an.run(SourceFile:2)
03-30 17:24:18.753  2131  7501 W ErrorProcessor:    ... 11 more
03-30 17:24:18.755  1748  1962 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9b8052a0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9b8033f0)
03-30 17:24:18.753  2131  7501 I AudioController: internalShutdown
03-30 17:24:18.760  2131  2131 I MicroDetectionWorker: onReady
03-30 17:24:18.778  2131  2131 I MicroDetector: Keeping mic open: false
03-30 17:24:18.778  2131  2131 I MicroDetectionWorker: #onError(false)
03-30 17:24:18.779  2131  7931 I DeviceStateChecker: DeviceStateChecker cancelled
03-30 17:24:18.782  1748  1962 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9b8052a0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9b8033f0)
03-30 17:24:18.833  1748  1962 I chatty  : uid=10029(com.android.systemui) RenderThread identical 4 lines
03-30 17:24:18.845  1748  1962 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9b8052a0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9b8033f0)
03-30 17:24:18.862  1640  1651 I GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock acquired by sendMessage(SET_REQUEST, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$GpsRequest@4e7b9c3)
03-30 17:24:18.875  1640  1653 I GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock released by handleMessage(SET_REQUEST, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$GpsRequest@4e7b9c3)
03-30 17:24:18.899  2005  8219 W ctxmgr  : [AclManager] No 3 for (accnt=account#-517948760#, com.google.android.gms(10013):UserVelocityProducer, vrsn=210915022, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null ,  pid = 2005 ,  featureId = null). Was: 3 for 1, account#-517948760# [CONTEXT service_id=47 ]
03-30 17:24:18.912  2005  2227 E ModuleIdSetter: exception when setting module id
03-30 17:24:18.912  2005  2227 E ModuleIdSetter: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get current module info in ModuleManager created with non-module Context
03-30 17:24:18.912  2005  2227 E ModuleIdSetter:    at com.google.android.chimera.config.ModuleManager.getCurrentModule(:com.google.android.gms@210915022@21.09.15 (040700-361652764):1)
03-30 17:24:18.912  2005  2227 E ModuleIdSetter:    at agza.a(:com.google.android.gms@210915022@21.09.15 (040700-361652764):4)
03-30 17:24:18.912  2005  2227 E ModuleIdSetter:    at agzd.Y(:com.google.android.gms@210915022@21.09.15 (040700-361652764):1)
03-30 17:24:18.912  2005  2227 E ModuleIdSetter:    at agvm.a(Unknown Source:3)
03-30 17:24:18.912  2005  2227 E ModuleIdSetter:    at tbx.a(:com.google.android.gms@210915022@21.09.15 (040700-361652764):0)
03-30 17:24:18.912  2005  2227 E ModuleIdSetter:    at syc.f(:com.google.android.gms@210915022@21.09.15 (040700-361652764):1)
03-30 17:24:18.912  2005  2227 E ModuleIdSetter:    at sya.e(:com.google.android.gms@210915022@21.09.15 (040700-361652764):1)
03-30 17:24:18.912  2005  2227 E ModuleIdSetter:    at tau.p(:com.google.android.gms@210915022@21.09.15 (040700-361652764):2)
03-30 17:24:18.912  2005  2227 E ModuleIdSetter:    at tau.v(:com.google.android.gms@210915022@21.09.15 (040700-361652764):3)
03-30 17:24:18.912  2005  2227 E ModuleIdSetter:    at tau.e(:com.google.android.gms@210915022@21.09.15 (040700-361652764):2)
03-30 17:24:18.912  2005  2227 E ModuleIdSetter:    at tay.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms@210915022@21.09.15 (040700-361652764):70)
03-30 17:24:18.912  2005  2227 E ModuleIdSetter:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-30 17:24:18.912  2005  2227 E ModuleIdSetter:    at agoi.iH(:com.google.android.gms@210915022@21.09.15 (040700-361652764):0)
03-30 17:24:18.912  2005  2227 E ModuleIdSetter:    at agoi.dispatchMessage(:com.google.android.gms@210915022@21.09.15 (040700-361652764):10)
03-30 17:24:18.912  2005  2227 E ModuleIdSetter:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
03-30 17:24:18.912  2005  2227 E ModuleIdSetter:    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

I have checked whether hermes is enabled or not and it is enabled. Any ideas why this may be crashing?

Comment: The Hermes team says: "Can you post this as an issue on the [React Native Github repository?](https://github.com/facebook/react-native). If there's a bug with how something is implemented you're more likely to get a response there. Also, looking at the stack trace you've posted, it doesn't look like it's a Hermes issue. The stack traces seem to be coming from `com.google.android.apps.gsa` and `com.google.android.gms` rather than a React Native app. It's likely the real stack trace of an issue is somewhere else, or perhaps it's a native code (C++) crash."

Comment: Alright thanks @thatotherguy